How to install old puppeteer on glitch.com?
I want to install puppeteer with Glitch.com.
However, when I run npm i puppeteer, it says that the Node version is not supported. (Node: v16.14.2, npm: v7.20.6)
So I tried to install Puppeteer version 19.6.1.
However, this version is deprecated and will not install.
Is there a way to install Puppeteer without changing the Node version?

What is the exact problem with this? " it says" - please, don't retell the message but list it. "this version is deprecated and will not install" - there's no link between deprecation status and that it's not installed

I'm sorry.The question is, is there a way to install Puppeteer without changing the Node version?

I don't see a reason for not doing this in the first place. If there's a problem on your side, the question doesn't explain it well. Older docs don't seem to have this section https://pptr.dev/guides/system-requirements , and package.json is the next place to check the compatibility. v19 is the latest to support node 16 indeed, https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/puppeteer-v19.11.1/packages/puppeteer-core/package.json#L34 . That a package is deprecated doesn't mean it cannot be installed and used

Why not upgrade the Node installed on your glitch project rather than downgrading puppeteer? If you want to install a particular version, use npm i puppeteer@some-version. Just because a version is old or deprecated doesn't mean you can't install it. You can install anything on npm as far as I know. Did you get some specific error?

I'm sorry. When I checked, I found that there was a mistake in the way I specified the version.

What mistake? Are you confirming that it's working, or is there still an issue you're facing? Please share full details and consider posting a self answer to help future visitors. Maybe sharing a link to your broken (or working) project would be helpful. I have Puppeteer working here, and apparently only Node up to 16 is supported by glitch currently.

At the current moment, Glitch only seems to support Node up to 16.x by default. There may be ways to circumvent it, but I haven't tried anything yet.
Working with the current system, if you're OK with a slightly older Puppeteer version, the following works for me. It's running at https://hello-puppeteer.glitch.me and https://glitch.com/~hello-puppeteer.
package.json:
{
  "name": "hello-puppeteer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "puppeteer": "^17.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
}

server.js:
const express = require("express");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const app = express();

app.get("/", async (request, response) => {
  let browser;
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ["--no-sandbox"]});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    const url = request.query.url ?? "https://pptr.dev";
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    response.send(await page.title());
  }
  catch (err) {
    response.send(err.message);
  }
  finally {
    await browser?.close();
  }
});

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${listener.address().port}`);
});

See also https://glitch.com/~jest-puppeteer for a Jest/Puppeteer setup.
For future visitors, if these projects or the information in this post becomes outdated, drop a comment and I'll upgrade. This thread can be used to track Glitch's progress on Node 18+ support.
